# How to freeze the keboard make the user cannot move it?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I call the on screen keyboard by this  code :

```
  showKeyboard()
    {
        string progFiles = @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink";
        string keyboardPath = Path.Combine(progFiles, "TabTip.exe");

         Process.Start(keyboardPath);

    }
```

Now I want to lock(freeze?) the keyboard on a default position, so the users cannot move it.

Only cannot move , but can still use it(e.g. input something...), how to achieve this?
[image]

Comment: Why would you want to interfere with users in that way? That would truly irritate me...

Comment: My tool is working on multi screens, there are some bugs, e.g. when we want to show the keyboard, sometime the keyboard is showed on screen 1, and sometimes showed on screen 2, so i want to set a position where the keyboard always show there.

Comment: You're implicitly stating that you know better than the user how they need to interact. Unless you're in an *exceptionally* constrained environment (e.g. a locked down kiosk), this is generally an unsound assumption. Let the user use *familiar* tools in whichever way they're used to working with them.

Comment: There's also a big difference between preventing users from moving the windows and getting the window to initially show on a particular screen. The latter is a lot nicer, but still constrains the users from what they prefer to do.

Comment: yes, I agree with that this may constrains the users , however currently I think it's not easy to solve the bugs, I have to freeze the position, so how can I freeze the position of the keyboard?